# cs-cart product import. Category duplicated or missing

Tags: import, product, cs-cart

I'm trying to import some products in cs-cart 4.1.2 and I have problem with the categories.

The first problem is that it duplicates the category.
The second problem is that only the last category is considered. For example I have the categories Bags & Accessories///Beauty and only "Beauty" is imported and "Bags & Accessories" is ingnored

Category Secondary category
Pocket Mirrors,Bags & Accessories///Beauty

I tried to export an existing product and reimport it exactly as it was, just changing the product code, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a problem with your CSV file. If you get an export from CS-Cart, open it with a text editor (eg. Sublime Text or Notepad++), and modify directly the text file. If you use eg. MS Excel, sometimes your CSV file will not be CS-Cart ready.

And please check, that your category name field is closed correctly:

```
...;"Bags & Accessories///Beauty";...
```

instead of

```
...;Bags & Accessories///Beauty;...
```